# Multiple requests when receiving mail in AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

Trying out the appengine mail api for the first time.  I built a servlet that responds to emails.  Relevant excerpts from my web.xml file and servlet class are included below.
The issue, however, is that after I sent a single email to the app at testing@[appid].appspotmail.com both of the following have happened:
1. Many log entries were recorded for requests to the handler servlet, and my mail quota for the day has been reached.  1/2 an hour later, I'm STILL seeing new log entries with failures

```
Uncaught exception from servlet com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$OverQuotaException: The API call mail.Send() required more quota than is available.
```

despite this, I have not actually received back a single email.

Also, there is the `recordMessage` method in my servlet that saves, for each mail request, an entity in the datastore, so I can view them.  My viewer servlet includes a counter, which, as I write this, is at 109 and still climbing, so more than 100 requests have been sent for the same email.

What am I doing wrong, I'd expect one call to the servlet per message, and then to actually receive an email!

My appengine-web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>bdl-mail-testing</application>
  <version>testing</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <inbound-services>
    <service>mail</service>
  </inbound-services>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Servlet section from my web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.bdl.appengine.mailtesting.MailHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>messageviewer</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.bdl.appengine.mailtesting.MessageViewerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>messageviewer</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the relevant methods from my mail handler servlet.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
  Properties props = new Properties();
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
  try {
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, req.getInputStream());
    String content = message.getContent().toString();
    recordMessage(message.getSubject(), content);
    replyTo(session, getFullPath(req), message);
  } catch (MessagingException ex) {
    log.log(Level.SEVERE, "An error occurred processing the message.", ex);
  }
}

private void replyTo(Session session, String path, Message message) throws MessagingException {
  Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
  String subject = message.getSubject();
  if (!subject.toLowerCase().startsWith("re: ")) {
    subject = "RE: " + subject;
  }
  msg.setSubject(subject);
  msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mail@bdl-mail-testing.appspot.com"));
  msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, message.getFrom());
  Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
  BodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();
  // Add a response
  part.setText(String.format("I got your message!\n\nReceived at: %s\n\n", path));
  multipart.addBodyPart(part);
  part = new MimeBodyPart();
  part.setDataHandler(message.getDataHandler());
  multipart.addBodyPart(part);
  msg.setContent(multipart);

  log.log(Level.INFO, String.format("Replied to a message: %s", subject));
  Transport.send(message);
}
```

Comment: You have a free quota of 100 sent mails per day. You have obviously reached that quota so you are now getting this error. But before you reached that quota you must have gotten a different kind of exception, right?

Comment: I understand why I'm getting this error now.  The question is why a single message sent to the appspotmail.com address is causing requests to be repeatedly sent to my handler servlet.  The quota error is expected under the circumstances, but the circumstances themselves make no sense.  Interestingly, I tried commenting out the line to actually send the reply email and re-uploading.  After that I have one more entry in the logs for handling a message (which finishes with ok status as there is no error on send) and then they stop.

Comment: and, to answer the question, no, there was no other error in the logs prior to the quota problems.  Something was just causing that one original message to be handled many many times.... and I think I was just an idiot and may have found the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, it was my own stupidity.
last line of replyTo was `Transport.send(message);` instead of the correct `Transport.send(msg);`  As a result, it kept resending the same message to itself and then reprocessing it.